# Wordpress display child category title with its links

Tags: php, wordpress

### Display Child categories without parent category included

I've tested several functions I saw online but nothing matches my requirements. Which is only displaying child category titles with its link. For example the Parent Category has two child categories. I want to display these two sub categories and apply a link for each of them that links to their respective category.

I was able to grabbed the posts inside the loop which included the thumbnail, post title, excerpt etc. But I was having a hard time achieving what I need.

And I found this solution online which achieved half of it.

```
function the_category_children($slug=""){
  if($categories       = get_the_category()):
    if($slug_category   = get_category_by_slug($slug)):
      foreach($categories as $category):
        echo (cat_is_ancestor_of($slug_category, $category)) ? $category->cat_name : '';
      endforeach;
    endif;
  endif;
}
```

The function above displays the two sub categories I need without including the parent category. But can you please help me on how to add separator for each of the category using this function? As well as the proper way to add a link that links to their respective category name? I have my own way of adding its link but I think it's so ugly which I think composed of extra unnecessary codes.

I hope someone could help me achieve this. Thanks in advance masters! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with this custom function I found [online](http://www.seanbehan.com/get-child-categories-of-parent-category-on-single-post-in-wordpress) and modified a little bit to meet my requirements.

```
function the_category_children($slug=""){
  $separator = ', ';
  $output = '';
  if($categories       = get_the_category()):
    if($slug_category   = get_category_by_slug($slug)):
      foreach($categories as $category):
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of($slug_category, $category)):
          $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
        endif;
      endforeach;
      echo trim( $output, $separator );
    endif;
  endif;
}
```

And calling this function the_category_children('category_name') inside the loop(content.php). ^_^